# Rounding numbers in C# producing too many decimal places

Tags: c#, math, floating-point, rounding, rounding-error

I'm trying to round a **float** down to 6 decimal places. Converting from double to float seems to pretty much do this, however in the process I've noticed some weirdness.
Whatever I do I seem to end up with fictitious extra decimal values on the end if I convert back to a **double** later on. I cannot avoid the conversion back to double - this in part of the application I cannot change, so I'm just trying to understand why my code is producing extra decimal places which never originally existed.

Eg;
I start with the following value and convert it to a double:

```
float foo = 50.8467178;
double bar = Convert.ToDouble32(foo); 
// Sorry line above originally said ToInt32 which was a typo :(
```

..then "bar" will be:   **50.846717834472656**  in the debugger.

**However**:

```
Convert.ToDouble(50.8467178).ToString()
```

...produces: **50.8467178**  (in the debugger). Ie it does not have the extra values.

Why have extra digits appeared on the end?
How can I stop this?
And finally: Why does calling ToString() on any of the above, often output a different number of decimal places compared with what the debugger shows?

Comment: Convert.ToInt32() to get to a double from a float?

Comment: You say that after `double bar = Convert.ToInt32(foo);` , "..then "bar" will be: 50.846717834472656 in the debugger." But as you convert it to an Int32, `bar` will be `50.0`?

Comment: I recommend reading this: [What every computer scientist should know about floating point numbers](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: @Matthew Watson 's link explains what you do wrong

Comment: @MatthewWatson: Please do not post that link just because floating-point is involved. It is inappropriate here because it does not explain the behavior reported in this question.

Answer (score 3):

You will have to use, `Math.Round` function.

```
Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(50.8467178)), 2);
```

You can take reference from [THIS](http://www.dotnetperls.com/math-round) link.

Or Do like this:

```
String.Format("{0:0.00}", Convert.ToDouble(50.8467178).ToString()); //two places
```

Please see [THIS](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-double/) link.

Comment: I really don't think he should be rounding the number itself; he needs to handle the rounding only when converting it to a string.

Comment: I have no control over where it's finally converted to a string. It's inside the XMLSerialiser class.

Comment: This does not explain the behavior reported in the question.

Comment: Do you need to convert to double?

Answer (score 0):

There's actually a few subtly different things happening in this example:

> I'm trying to round a float down to 6 decimal places. Converting from double to float seems to pretty much do this

If you need to round, use the [Round](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75ks3aby.aspx) method. Converting can result in a loss of precision, and floating point types aren't infinitely precise to begin with.

> Why have extra digits appeared on the end?

Internally floats and doubles are represented in binary according to the [IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) standard. Your number, 50.8467178 can't be exactly represented in binary, much like 1/3 can't be exactly represented in decimal (without repeating digits). According to the standard, the number as a float is stored as `0x424B6304`. This is precise to 24 bits, or 6-9 decimal digits. Now, reinterpreting that number according to the standard we get:

```
0x424B6304
= 1.58895993232727 * 2^5
= 50.84671783447264
```

The display, whether it be the debugger or calling the `ToString()` method, is smart enough to know that only the first 6-9 digits mattered (which is consistent with the IEEE standard). Taking the maximum 9 digits, the float would be displayed as `50.8467178`.

However, when this number is converted to a double, it's binary value **does not change.** Its internal bit pattern sure does, but the binary number is still interpreted as `1.58895993232727 * 2^5`. The problem is that doubles are precise to 53 bits, or 15-17 decimal digits. So now when displayed, 15-17 digits are shown rather than the original 6-9. So, its not that there are extra digits when its converted to a double, *the digits were already there*.

Now when there is no intermediate float conversion, 50.8467178 can be more precisely represented using a double. This is stored as `0x40496C613FB5F875`. Now I haven't done the math on that one yet, but with the above procedure, we would get something like `50.84671780000000000000000000023155`. Considering only the first 15-17 digits, results in the 50.8467178 seen in the display (with the significant 0s omitted).

> How can I stop this?

Don't round by casting to floats, they only have 6-9 accurate digits. The decimal type is normally appropriate for when decimal precision is needed, but since you can't change that part of the code, using the `Round` method should be precise enough for your application (as long as you stay under 1,000,000,000).

> Why does calling ToString() on any of the above, often output a different number of decimal places compared with what the debugger shows?

I've been skirting around this issue to try and keep things simple and sequential. I've been giving a range for precision in decimal digits: 6-9 for floats, 15-17 for doubles. Taking doubles for example, the `ToString()` method by default returns a string with 15 decimal digits. You could, however, force it to return 17 decimal digits by calling `ToString("G17")` [(doc)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kfsatb94.aspx), but there would be no guarantee those two digits are significant. I suspect that the debugger calls this version for its display, which is why it differs from `ToString()`.

---

**Further reading:** [IEEE Arithmetic, by Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_math.html). It's quite technical though.

Answer (score -1):

The literal 50.8467178 is a double by default so it is implicitly converted to a float when asigned to foo. And because float has a smaller percision it is rounded and not so acurate. You should use 50.8467178f when you asign to foo because it is a float literal. In the second example you are converting a double literal to double so there is no change and it prints it as is.

Comment: The literal was just for my question.. I don't use literals in my code, but thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: This does not explain the behavior reported in the question.

Answer (score -1):

Doing this:

```
Convert.ToDouble(50.8467178).ToString()
```

Is the same as doing this:

```
(50.8467178).ToString();
```

Since the implicit type of the number is `double`, and the conversion does nothing.

But when you start with the number as a `float`, the conversion does take effect, and it is known that `double` messes up many times (this case, as well as when comparing values, etc...).

I would suggest using `decimal`, direct casts and `Equals` instead of `==`.

Answer (score -1):

The reason that the extra decimal places appear is likely because of a slight precision loss when converting from double to float (floating point conversions are never perfect).

If you need to round the number then after you've done the conversion you can do:

```
result = Math.Round(result, 2);
```

Edit: Given Eric's comment below, here is some extra info:

A `float` in C# is a 32 bit floating point representation of a number, whereas a `double` is 64 bit. Not every number is perfectly representable by a floating point number. When you convert from the 32 bit float to the 64 bit double you've got 32 extra bits to fill in with information. This extra information ends up being the extra digits that you see:

```
float foo = 50.8467178f;
double bar = System.Convert.ToDouble(foo);
System.Console.WriteLine(bar); // prints 50.8467178344727 on my machine
```

Since the original number is not perfectly representable in floating point, the output ends up being a slightly different number because of the conversion process.

If you need to maintain precision for this number you'll need to use `decimal` values instead:

```
decimal foo = 50.8467178M;
double bar = System.Convert.ToDouble(foo);
System.Console.WriteLine(bar); // prints 50.8467178 on my machine
```

If you can't use `decimal` (e.g. the `float` is the output of a third party library or something) then the rounding approach is the next best option:

```
float foo = 50.8467178f;
double bar = System.Convert.ToDouble(foo);
bar = System.Math.Round(bar, 7);
System.Console.WriteLine(bar); // prints 50.8467178 on my machine
```

Comment: This answer is correct that part of the problem is the rounding error caused by conversion to float, but this is incomplete because it does not explain why displaying a value derived from a narrower precision produces more digits than displaying a value derived from a wider precision. It is also incorrect to state that floating-point conversions are never perfect. In IEEE-754, conversions from `float` to `double` are error free, and conversions from `double` to `float` are error free if the original value is representable as a `float`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Although IEEE specifies that an operation x+y must yield the best floating-point representation of the nominal value of x plus the nominal value of y, that does not mean that x really "represents" its nominal value.  The nominal values of 0.1f and (double)0.1f may be the same, but the semantic meanings differ.  There is no double value whose semantic meaning matches that of 0.1f.  Indeed, I would posit that converting a float to a double generally alters its semantic meaning more than does converting a double to a float.

Comment: @supercat: (a) This notion of “semantic meaning” is outside the bounds of the programming language and not relevant to this question. (b) By this standard, the semantics meanings of `2` and `2l` differ, so integer conversions are never perfect.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: The normal purpose of floating-point values is to stand in for real numerical quantities.  Neither a `Single` nor `Double` really *represents* an exact power-of-two fraction.  If it did, `0.1f` shouldn't compile, but should have to be written as `0.100000001490116119384765625f`.  The pattern of bits produced by `0.1f`, however, doesn't really represent that precise quantity, but instead "something that's probably within a 0.1 parts per million of 0.1000000015", making it a correct representation of the quantity 1/10.

Comment: @supercat: No such meaning is specified in the IEEE 754 standard or in language standards with which I am familiar. The notion that floating-point objects represent intervals is folklore passed apocryphally. To use floating-point correctly, use the IEEE 754 or other applicable specification.

Comment: There is only one `Int64` value which maps to the `Int32` value 2.  By contrast, there are millions of `double` values which map to `0.1f`.  The IEEE standard says that math must be performed as though it were computed with exact values and then rounded, but that doesn't mean that `0.1f` should be considered an exact quantity which is greater than 0.100000000558793544769287109375.  Rather, it should represent something which is indistinguishable from any numerical values which would share the same `float` representation.

Comment: I would posit that a cast `var woggle=(fnord)woozle` should throw an exception if no possible value of `fnord` would be a legitimate representation of `woozle`.  Thus, if a cast does not throw an exception, either the casting code is broken or else `woggle` holds a `fnord` which legitimately represents `woozle`.  The fact that `(float)0.1` and `(float)0.100000001` share same bit pattern implies to me that that bit pattern is a legitimate `float` representation of both `0.1` and `0.100000001`.